# Inserting methods 'Controllers' in 'Services'

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have a class that manages my uploaders. It makes use of the plugin file-uploader 'and complements other information and rules of my application.

I'm trying to create a service that manages some behaviors of the application and notice that the 'Services' does not recognize some methods used in the controllers. Method 'redirect' for example works only on Controllers and are not recognized in Services.

In one of my services I do I forward a file of type 'File' as parameter to the service but attributes this 'File' as 'OriginalFilename', size, etc are not recognized in the 'Service'. Someone could tell me how do I get these attributes from 'File' and these methods as 'redirect' are recognized in the 'Service'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you may be a bit confused about the roles of Controllers vs. Services in Grails.

The usual pattern is for a Controller to get information sent by the user's browser (binding), validate it, and then if necessary, invoke a Service method to do something with that data. Once the service method returns, the Controller then either renders a view, forwards, or redirects.

So, your service should not be trying to do a redirect. That is the job of a controller, and that is why that functionality is not available to your service.